# Fixed a bug in box2d, but I don't know why?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, box2d

I created a sprite in cocos2dx, and bound it to PhysicsSprite. Then I add a Button on this sprite, but when I move this PhysicsSprite, the Button doesn't move, though it's target area is right.

Then, I find this in PhysicsSprite override Draw() function:

> ```
>    if (isDirty())
>    {
>        syncPhysicsTransform();
>    }    
>    Sprite::draw(renderer, _transform, flags);
> ```

Then I change a value...

> ```
>    if (isDirty())
>    {
>        syncPhysicsTransform();
>        _transformUpdated = true;
>    }    
>    Sprite::draw(renderer, _transform, flags);
> ```

And it works.

But I don't know why it succeeds, please tell me.